# AMP page if you use a browser back, you can't click any other links

Tags: amp-html

I created my first AMP page.
There are some hyperlinks in the AMP page.
The link is to the original page, not the AMP page.
There is only one serious problem there.

Go to the AMP page from "Google Search" and click on the hyperlink that takes you to the original page in the AMP page.
If you go to the original link (page) and then return to the AMP page in the browser back, the other links will not be clickable.

This phenomenon has been confirmed in iOS 13.3.1.　(Safari, chrome)
I read the documentation, but I couldn't solve it.

Also, I am very new to these things.
If there is anything misleading, please let me know.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. We will investigate that matter.